# How to define a function that refers to previous values in a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

So I'm trying to define a function which looks like this mathematically: M_n = M_n-1(1+g) –– where n and n-1 are subscripts and g is a constant.

I want to do this within a range of 1 to 100. I already have the values for n=1. The code I have till now looks like this

```
for num in range(1,100):
    if num <= 1:
        print(M_n)    # since I already have an M_n for n=1
```

So, from n=2 onwards, how do I ensure that M_n refers its previous value and does the following operation on it: M_n-1(1+g)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output? A list, or just the last number?

Comment: It will be better if you tell what your M_n looks like

Comment: A better way to write your function is M_n = M_1*((1+g)**(n-1))

Comment: @Jondiedoop my expected output is a list

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, that's how i wrote it while coding the function. In my question above, I wrote it in its mathematical form rather than its programming form. My apologies for the delayed response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M_(n-1)` is just the most recent calculation, the one produced in the previous iteration of the loop. Store that in a variable and refer to it again the next iteration.

If you don't need the intermediary `M_n` values, just keep a single updated result:

```
m = 1  # M_0, so the starting value for the sequence
for n in range(1, 100):
    # update M_n for the current iteration
    m *= 1 + g
```

or you can append to a list (at which point the preceding value is always the last value in the list):

```
m = [1]  # list with M_0, so the starting value for the sequence
for n in range(1, 100):
    # add M_n for the current iteration
    m.append(m[-1] * (1 + g))
```

or use [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to accumulate all values:

```
from itertools import accumulate, chain

calc_mn = lambda prev, n: prev * (1 + g)
# calculate starting from [1] for M_0
m = accumulate(chain([1], range(1, 100)), calc_mn)
```

In the latter case `m` is an iterator yielding results as you iterate.

Comment: My expected output is a list, so I do need the intermediary values. Could you please give more detail on 

"M_(n-1) is just the most recent calculation, the one produced in the previous iteration of the loop. Store that in a variable and refer to it again the next iteration"? My apologies if this is basic, I'm a beginner in Python.

Comment: The second method worked! Thank you! One follow-up though. It generated a bunch of lists. How do I keep the last one and delete the rest?

Comment: @M.Jain: that method creates a single list, `m`, not a bunch of lists.

Comment: @M.Jain: are you perhaps printing `m` inside the loop? Then you are just writing out the current state of the list each iteration.

Comment: Yes, I was printing m inside the loop. Thank you so much for your help!